# Map Sitecore "Name Value List" field to NameValue collection

Tags: glass-mapper

Im trying to map Sitecore "Name Value List" field to NameValueCollection using below code which is not working.

```
[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
public interface IManifest
{
    string Title { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    string Author { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("ErrorMessages")]
    NameValueCollection ErrorMessages { get; set; }
}
```

all other field values are being mapped except for "ErrorMessages". Does it require additional code/configuration to achieve this?

Comment: There seems to be a data mapper for both `NameValueCollection` and `Dictionary<,>` types (and has been for a few years) which both uses `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` under the hood, so theoretically your code should work unless you are using a very old version.

Have you tried using `Dictionary<string, string>` instead?

Comment: I'm using version 4.3 which is almost latest one. Dictionary<string, string> is not working as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can achieve this without any custom code.

But I did find a quick workaround here https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/11/t/3026 :

```
[SitecoreField(Name_Value_ListFieldName)]
public virtual string Name_Value_List_Raw  {get; set;}  

public NameValueCollection Name_Value_List  {get {return 
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Name_Value_List_Raw); }}
```

Comment: Well..the problem was my item template with this field was not published properly.(completely my mistake).. I've already seen this question on community and tried this workaround which didn't work.. proper publish and this answer worked for me.. thank you Marek..